# How can I use Gson here to send back the list to the jsp page?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, servlets, gson

In one case a `servlet A` sends an IP to a remote server with the hope that the server will send back the list of files shared by that IP :

```
Servlet A

connection.openConnection(); // Sends the IP as the query parameters
if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {  
    requestDispatcher.forward(request,response); // Forward to ShowFiles.jsp
} else { // Error ! }
```

***Note: 'ShowFiles.jsp' is a jsp page that will show the list it will receive from the server.***

Okay ! Now the `servlet` on the server,let us name it `B`, receives the query parameter and checks if the database has any file corresponding to the IP received. If there is/are files shared it sends back the list of names,otherwise a message suggesting that no file has been shared.

```
Servlet B (On server that receives IP as query parameter)

String ip = getAttribute("IP");
if( hasSharedFile(ip) ) {
  list = fetchList(ip); // Basically an ArrayList<String>
  // SEND THIS LIST BACK TO THE CLIENT
} else {
   // Return a message saying,No file has been shared till with the server
  }
```

To send this list by the `servlet B` *(on the remote server)* to `ShowFiles.jsp` *(to which the servlet A dispatched the request)* I was suggested to use `JSON`,rather `Gson`. How can I use `Gson` to send this list to `ShowFiles.jsp` ?

I have never used Gson,so I know nothing.

Comment: Some information on [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). And also some on [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Servlet B (On server that receives IP as query parameter)

String ip = getAttribute("IP");
if( hasSharedFile(ip) ) {
  list = fetchList(ip); // Basically an ArrayList<String>
  // SEND THIS LIST BACK TO THE CLIENT

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(list, resp.getWriter());

} else {
   // Return a message saying,No file has been shared till with the server
  }
```

Servlet A

```
if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> list = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()),ArrayList.class);
```

.jsp read from reader

```
<%@page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

<%
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList list = gson.fromJson(request.getReader(), ArrayList.class);
// ...
%>
```

Comment: and how do I retrieve this on the client side ? _(ShowFiles.jsp)_

Comment: It gets me `null pointer exception` in the `jsp` when I am not forwarding but redirecting to the `jsp`. What do I do now ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta show me your redirect code. maybe redirection got the http body lost

Comment: [Redirection code](http://i45.tinypic.com/2cde3a1.jpg) and [the error shown in the browser](http://i50.tinypic.com/5vorqh.jpg)

Comment: @SuhailGupta see how your program works and why redirect does not work http://i50.tinypic.com/vonc0i.png

Comment: I am getting `null` from `Servlet-B` when the file has been shared. I don't know why.[I have uploaded the code of servlet-A and Servlet-B at github.](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/Samples) . I also uploaded [flow of what's happening](http://i49.tinypic.com/25klav6.jpg).

Comment: @SuhailGupta at which line

Comment: `49th` line which is _System.out.println("LIST---------------------->" + list);_

Comment: can you explain the reason for `null` ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta i am debugging

Comment: @SuhailGupta fix your bug see my diff at  https://github.com/suhailgupta03/Samples/pull/1/files#diff-3

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23514/discussion-between-farmer1992-and-suhail-gupta)